# How to send data in the HTTP request body when using an HTML form?

Tags: html, http, http-post, forms

The HTTP spec says that a POST request can contain an arbitrary body of data.

An HTML `form` element can POST to a URL and may contain `input` elements, but those `input` elements get turned into a query string.

How can I get a `form` to also send along data in the body of the HTTP POST request that it sends when its submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 8):

> *The HTTP spec says that a POST request can contain an arbitrary body of data.*

That's correct. There are in turn however several specifications of the format of that data. In case of HTML forms, most commonly used is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, followed by `multipart/form-data`. You can set it via the `enctype` attribute of the HTML `<form>` element. See also chapter [17.13.4 Form Content Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) of the HTML specification.

---

> *An HTML form element can POST to a URL and may contain input elements, but those input elements get turned into a query string.*

That's indeed how `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works. Do note that this query string actually represents the whole HTTP request body! So the request body is definitely not empty as you seem to think.

---

> *How can I get a form to also send along data in the body of the HTTP POST request that it sends when its submit button is pressed?*

It thus actually already does that. If you intented to send a copy of the HTML DOM tree representation of the form itself, as somewhat hinted in the previous statement, then you can achieve that with a little help of JavaScript as follows:

```
<form onsubmit="this.source.value=this.outerHTML">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="source" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The whole HTML DOM tree representation of the form is then in string format available as request parameter with name `source`.

Answer (score 4):

Use javascript to send an ajax request when the button is pressed and cancel the form submission.  Form submits will always be name/value pairs.  XForms can send customized data but if this is for public use it'll be years before XForms is supported by the majority of browsers in use, if ever.

Comment: If I use AJAX to do the POST, then the browser will not automagically handle the HTTP response, and I want it to. In other words, I am looking for an answer to the question that doesn't rely on JavaScript, but just HTML.