# error with more than one @Body field - retrofit2 beta3

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am just starting out with retrofit for android. I am getting an error when I try to specify 2 fields for the body of a post request:

Multiple @Body method annotations found. (parameter #2) for method

The Call is defined in my API interface file as:

```
@POST("auth/login")
Call<UserData> login(@Body String username, @Body String password);
```

And I create the call with:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
Call<UserData> call = service.login(username, password);
```

error is generated when the call is created (do not have a chance to execute it).
When I remove one of the body fields it seems to work fine.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using multiple @Body is bad idea, because @Body here means message Body of HTML POST.

(Detail: [How to send data in the HTTP request body when using an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971112/how-to-send-data-in-the-http-request-body-when-using-an-html-form))

I suggest you to define a class containing both username and password, like below.

```
public class LoginInformation {
    String username;
    String password;
}
```

And, fill your information on that class instance, and use that.

```
@POST("auth/login")
Call<UserData> login(@Body LoginInformation loginInformation);
```

Answer (score 6):

Any HTTP request is allowed to contain only one [message body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) , if you try adding two `@Body` parameters you will get this message `"Multiple @Body method annotations found."`

And you can fix it by following this:

You can send multiple or different type of objects at the same time using `HashMap` or single type, for example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("password", "123456");
map.put("username", "Jake Warthon");
```

or

```
public class User(){
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }
}

User user = new User(); 
user.setUsername("Jake Warthon")
user.setPassword("123456");
map.put("user", user);
```

You can append more data (like different type of objects) in a single body if you want (optional)

```
map.put("user", user);
map.put("authorization", "12uh3u12huhcd2");
map.put("something", someobject);
```

You have to change the body type of the request to receive a Hashmap or User

```
@POST("auth/login")
Call<UserData> login(@Body HashMap map);
```

or

```
@POST("auth/login")
Call<UserData> login(@Body User user);
```

Finally you pass the data to service like you already did.

```
Call<UserData> call = service.login(map);
```

or

```
Call<UserData> call = service.login(user);
```

And remember, the server side have to implement it correctly to receive the data as a map.